# cross debug of gcc compiler and vs2013

Tags: debugging, gcc, visual-studio-2013

I use gcc to compile ffmpeg to static library (.a) and invoke it success in visual studio 2013. but I can not add some break point in function of ffmpeg and can not step into function of ffmpeg ,can anybody help me?

By the way,I compile ffmpeg with -g3 flag and invoke program used debug mode but I still step into function of ffmpeg

```
codec_context->width = header.biWidth;
codec_context->height = abs(header.biHeight);
codec_context->codec_id = AV_CODEC_ID_H264;
codec_context->codec_tag = media_type.Subtype()->Data1;
codec_context->bits_per_coded_sample = header.biBitCount;
codec_context->workaround_bugs = FF_BUG_AUTODETECT;
codec_context->error_concealment = FF_EC_DEBLOCK | FF_EC_GUESS_MVS;
codec_context->err_recognition = AV_EF_CAREFUL;
codec_context->idct_algo = FF_IDCT_AUTO;
codec_context->skip_loop_filter = AVDISCARD_DEFAULT;
codec_context->refcounted_frames = 1;
codec_context->thread_count = 1;
codec_context->opaque = this;
codec_context->using_dxva = 1;
codec_context->flags2 |= CODEC_FLAG2_SHOW_ALL;
if (avcodec_open2(codec_context.get(), codec, nullptr) < 0)
    return false;
```